# How to continuously vary inductance in the range \$[-A, A]\$, A>0?

Tags: components, impedance, inductance, component-selection

I require an inductor whose inductance varies continuously as a function of some parameter \$p\$, like a bias voltage or something else that is easily user-controllable (not frequency as I require it for something else). It may look like \$f(p) = a\,p\$ for a certain range \$p \in [-b, b]\$. Also, \$f(p)\$ needs to be negative for some range of \$p\$ and positive for another range. I have an idea about this but if anybody can suggest something better and less complex, that would be great.

Let say we can vary the inductance of some component \$Z_1\$ by varying \$p\$. I came across something called [Negative Impedance Converter (NICs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter) which can be used to get an effective negative impedance (hence an effective negative inductance) in the circuit. I thought of using \$Z_1\$ in NIC and then another \$Z_1\$ in series with the NIC to get total impedance \$f(p)\$:
$$
f(p) = f(p_2-p_1) = Z_{NIC}(p_1) + Z_1(p_2)
$$
Here, \$p_1, p_2 \in [0, b]\$ can be varied independently and can be set to 0 appropriately to get \$p \in [-b, b]\$. So, if you can think of some component \$Z_1\$ whose inductance can vary continuously wrt some parameter, I think this can work.

I'm not much familiar with electronics so I don't know if something like this even exists. We can vary inductance by varying the core of the inductor, but I don't think that will work in my case.

#### EDIT 1: Background

I adding some details on the problem that I am trying to solve, as the comments suggest this might help. This is actually a physics problem. I am using electrical circuits of inductors and capacitors to model some properties of graphene. The equations that I get for the circuits the similar to Hamiltonian of graphene. Here, the inductances and capacitances act like some parameters in the Hamiltonian and I want to vary these parameters to see how the behavior of the system changes. These parameters can also have negative values, this is why I'm trying to use NIC so that I can get an effective -ve value in the equations. What I want is a way to continuously vary these the inductances and capacitances (such that they can also have negative values) wrt a parameter. For varying capacitances, I think use of varicap diodes might help (but not sure about it). But I couldn't find something similar for inductances.

Comment: *We can vary inductance by varying the core of the inductor* Indeed that's the only solution that I know. And that gives you a positive inductance only. OK, you can also make a (simulated) variable inductor using electronics but that has limitations. You need to be an EE to understand those limitations. Such "simulated" inductors can only be used in circuits like filters and oscillators.

Comment: *I don't think that will work in my case* explain **WHY** you think that. Also explain what you need a variable inductor for. As many that are new to electronics you loose yourself in **finding a certain component** instead of **describing what your problem is**. You admit that you know little about electronics so why then assume that the variable inductance is the only solution? Maybe there are solutions that are common but that are unknown to you.

Comment: .. what do you expect negative *inductance* to mean? The "negative impedance" gives a hint - you might be able to achieve a particular set of voltage/current curves with an opamp, some clever circuitry, and an external power source, but that's not the same as a physical inductor.

Comment: Explain in normal terms what you are trying to do. That's how to get the best from this site.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Please see the edit. I was avoiding varying the core because I wanted some simpler way of doing this. Also, since the varicap diodes use a bias voltage for varying capacitance, I wanted to use the same parameter for varying the inductances. I don't think I can use something other than inductor because I'm modifying a circuit that was published in a paper. I have not made anything from scratch.

Comment: @pjc50 please see the edit. I only want the inductances and capacitances to work out in the equations. I don't think that not having a physical "negative" inductor would make a difference to the system's behavior.

Comment: @Andyaka please see the edit. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: And what value range of inductance are you considering and what excitation signal are you considering?

Comment: OK, so this is a **modelling** issue! For some systems an electrical equivalent can be suitable (for example a mechanical system, read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_graph ), then it is easier to model electro-mechanical systems. The options I see for you: 1) use **Matlab** (or GNU Octave, which is freeware) to do your modelling. In Matlab you will have **full control** instead of being limited to what an electrical circuit simulator allows. 2) Use an electrical simulator but **write your own model** instead of using non-existing components.

Comment: I hope you realize how you're **making your own life difficult** (and ours as well) by 1) not fully explaining what you wanted to achieve 2) asking for electrical components, then us EEs think you want to **build some circuit**. But no, you want to **model something**. EEs do lots of modelling (the good ones do) either in Matlab/Octave or a circuit simulator. I mainly use Cadence Spectre which has a build-in modelling language: VerilogA which can be used to define the behavior of **non existing components** like your inductor. But I urge you to try Matlab/Octave as that's more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

> [OP:] The equations that I get for the circuits the similar to Hamiltonian of graphene. Here, the inductances and capacitances act like some parameters in the Hamiltonian and I want to vary these parameters to see how the behavior of the system changes.

It appears that you are trying to *simulate* "the behavior of the system". Excluding the possibility that, in order "to model some properties of graphene", you have chosen to build an [analog computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer), the insertion of lumped circuit elements into the field models of solvers for the integrated EM/materials engineering problems is a well-established approach because of the topological similarities between the finite difference scheme and circuits.

But, to begin with, you have to make sure: for the specific physical properties of the material and the environment (temperature, external fields) that you are going to study ("an effective -ve value in the equations", what is it?), the quantum effects do not prevail and the purely classical-electromagnetic "Hamiltonian" is a reasonable approximation.

Then, you start with the generation of equivalent circuits for your problem (circuit extraction) -- the circuits that include resistors, inductors, capacitors, and voltage/current controlled voltage/current sources. The resulting elements may have non-physical values (negative inductances, for example) for some cells or even everywhere. The netlists for extracted circuits are fed into a circuit simulator (specifically, you can use SPICE), and you can expect to obtain the solution. To plot the dependence of the solutions on "inductances and capacitances" (if this is the right way to investigate your system), you run SPICE simulations with the parametric sweep.

This technique (except for parametric sweep plots) is well summarized in the introduction section of the article [Automated netlist generation for 3D electrothermal and electromagnetic field problems](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10825-019-01368-6).

> In order to analyse complex electromagnetic (EM) problems, two main routes can be identified. First, a numerical approach for solving the full set of Maxwell ’s field equations offers the advantage of capturing all relevant effects but can be very demanding in terms of computational resources.
>
> ...
>
> Secondly, one may use compact models to obtain an efficient
> representation of a complex system. For example, electrical engineers
> employ circuits to model and describe the behaviour of complex
> devices.

The rest of the article is a detailed report of contrivances used to accomplish the circuit extraction, the coupling of EM and materials science equations, the elaboration of the description and implementation of boundary conditions and excitations, etc. The reference section, in itself, is a quite comprehensive review of the use of lumped-circuit-element model for solving integrated EM/materials science problems.

If you find this article technically difficult for understanding, I recommend to you a very good introduction into this technique: [Electric circuit diagram equivalents of fields](https://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Electric.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I require an inductor whose inductance varies continuously as a function of some parameter , like a bias voltage or something else that is easily user-controllable

That could be a [saturable reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturable_reactor).